# Most original form of the Hebrew Bible/Tanach

Tags: hebrew, tanach, product-recommendation

Not sure if they are the same thing (the Hebrew Bible and the Tanach). I read in [this link](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/do-jewish-people-have-a-collection-of-books-which-are-the-equivelant-of-the-chri/7281#7281) that "there are many different Jewish translations of the Hebrew Bible". This kind of confuses me because I thought Jews were Hebrew, but then again, I don't know too much. But basically I'm asking where I can find the most original form of the Hebrew Bible/Tenach (are these the same thing? Looking for the collection of 24 books.)? I would like two forms of resources, if possible, please: An **actual book** (in English, since I can't copy+paste the text into a translator >_<) as well as a **good online resource** (online bible/tanach). Not looking for a "Jewish translation", because as said in that link "translation is a form of interpretation" and I don't want an interpretation. I want the real thing :)

PS - Sorry if my lack of knowledge makes my questions horribly worded.

Comment: Shredder, you can't really get away from interpretation.  Much of the Bible is cryptic and must be approached with one of any number of methods.  Also, the translation of many words are unknown except by trying to break them down and comparing them with similar words elsewhere in the Bible, which has multiple approaches as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Crown

Comment: You can also use this online copy with Rashi commentary which has both Hebrew and English http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm

Comment: An example of the problem with translation to any languages can be found in the list of non-kosher birds. Many translations will **transliterate** the names of the birds as we may not be sure which they are. Additionally, the word for *bird*, עף, includes a type that is usually translated as *bat*. Thus, the word itself does not necessarily mean *bird* as used in modern English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Hebrew Bible and the Tanach are the same thing. Most of the books were written originally in Hebrew and a couple were written at least partially in Aramaic. Whether the text we have today is the same as it was originally is subject to dispute. (With regard to non-Pentateuch books, most everyone agrees our text is not 100% the original.) However, the differences between different texts are very few and hardly matter.

One of the most accurate versions of the Masoretic text is the Koren Tanakh, available to be purchased [here](https://korenpub.com/koren/intusd/tanakh/tanakh-bible/classic-compact-tanakh). (I believe it has textual variants listed in the back.) The most prominent online resources are [Mechon-Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0.htm) and [Wikisource](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90).

I'm not sure what confused you about "There are many different Jewish translations of the Hebrew Bible". The Tanach has been translated into many languages many times. If you were to compare English translations produced by Jews, then I have no doubt that you would find yourself very confused. Each translator has their own view and interpretation to which they bias their translation.

Comment: I was confused because I thought a Jewish translation *would* be Hebrew, or rather Hebrew is the language of Jews? >_< Thought the two were the same, so I didn't see why a translation was needed for the Jews. But I see what you mean, "English translations by Jews".

Comment: I'm sorry, is there an English version of that book? I'll update my question >_<

Comment: Bah! I guess that defeats the purpose. Guess I'm screwed on the book part.

Comment: @Shredder, Ah, I assumed you were looking for exclusively Hebrew editions; as you noted, translations do defeat the purpose of your question. If you're looking to compare translations, though, check out [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11616/489).

Comment: @Shredder, re "I was confused because I thought a Jewish translation would be Hebrew, or rather Hebrew is the language of Jews": There are Jewish translations, though, in the sense that they try to translate in accordance with Jewish traditions of explaining the scripture.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't read Hebrew :( I was hoping that I could use an online translator for these texts, but the translations are coming out really strange..

Comment: Are there any English translations that seek to nail pinpoint accuracy of the original/traditional (before 1 CE) texts?

Comment: @msh210 That is exactly what I *don't* want. That will contain biases towards the Judaism in the state and time of which is was written, also what people *think* when God might have intended something different.

Comment: @Shredder, Unfortunately, pinpoint accuracy, when it comes to translation (especially of Hebrew) is not possible. Some words in Hebrew have meanings that are intended to be understood based on context, which of course is subject to interpretation. Other words have specific connotations that are not the same in the language being translated into; sometimes the reverse may be true, in that the translation connotes something that was not there in the Hebrew text. There are too many subtleties.

Comment: @Shredder, re "Are there any English translations that seek to nail pinpoint accuracy": Yes, Young's [so-called] Literal Translation ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_Literal_Translation)) seeks to. It fails, though; and I assume it has Christian biases.

Comment: @jake Dang..that makes sense. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @msh210 That's also what I don't want. How can one discern for themselves the original words of the Lord, when the only text they have is either bias towards Judaism or Christianity? :\

Comment: @Shredder, learn Hebrew. It's not *that* difficult. I saw an estimate (which could well have been completely made up, but anyway) that a reasonably intelligent adult with no knowledge of Hebrew can learn enough Biblical Hebrew in a year to be able to read _Tanach_.

Comment: @Shredder learn the original language.

Comment: Oh, I remember now where I saw that estimate: in [_This is My God_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_My_God:_The_Jewish_Way_of_Life). @Shredder

Comment: I've got some text (a couple of verses; you already know which ones ;) from the Mechon-Mamre resource that you provided. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to learn the language myself. Is there any way I can have this text translated for me, accurately and without bias towards any particular belief? Does anyone know of any Hebrew translation services or websites that can help me with this?

Comment: @Shredder, As already noted, exact translation without the bias of interpretation is impossible, in those verses (end of Daniel 9, I assume) just as much as any others. The problem with online translators, besides for being notoriously inaccurate, is that the intent is probably translation of Modern Israeli Hebrew, which, although derived from it, is very different than Biblical Hebrew. Your best bet is probably to ask something on Hermeneutics.SE about what the most strict translation would be, although I'm not sure about what type of questions they find appropriate there.

Comment: @jake Good idea! I will try the [question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/accurate-translations-of-original-scripts-text) on Hermeneutics.SE

Comment: Blarg I thought you were going to point to a Breuer based text like http://www.jerusalemcrown.com/website_en/index.asp?page_id=15. Why would you still choose to advertise Koren as most accurate?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Koren is quite well-known for their attention to the accuracy of the text (unlike many other chumashim you might find at your local Judaica shop), while also being quite affordable and easy on the eyes. I didn't claim it was the most accurate of texts.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, while there are different opinions about the "Best translation", there are also different opinions about the "original text".

The hebrew text you will find in most Tanachs today is called the [Masoratic Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text).  (It means "Traditional Text")  This text was corrected between the 7th and 10th centuries, as various communities were found to have slightly different texts from each other.   The differences in the texts are minimal.  However during the 2nd century there were a group known as the "Tikun Sophrim" which means Scribal corrections.  The corrections were needed because of the events surrounding the destruction of the Temples and the scattering of the Jewish people.  Texts from the Dead Sea scrolls show slight differences in the text dating back between 150 BCE and 70 CE.

Now, as for translations, the first officially approved one that Jews use is called "The translation of Anokoles" which was written in Aramaic.  Since then there have been many translations based on the country in which various Jews have lived, as well as depending on the commentators used to understand the Hebrew.  The Current Artscroll translation for example relies heavily on the commentary of Rashi for it's translation.

It should be noted that the translations and texts available to us, really do differ on very minor things, but it should also be clear to everyone that the text has been corrected over the many centuries in exile.

Comment: Interesting. I was hoping that there would be texts available from before 1 CE. You would think that it wouldn't be impossible for a Hebrew who knows English to accurately translate these traditional texts to English without any biases, etc. There has to be English translations for these texts that seek to nail such accuracy, do you know of any?

Comment: @Shredder the concept is impossible.  The Torah is written in poetry, not mathematical notation. Even not translating the Hebrew, but two hebrew speakers will read a verse differently.

Comment: @NickRolando   The way to get something non bias, is to use a concordance.. and a biblical hebrew dictionary. There is also a translation called YLT (young's literal translation). An example of different translations.. is in Genesis, The hebrew word Off it means flying creature or winged creatures. But since many translations try to do it word for word, they just say bird. Though technically it'd include a fly. A translation is often like a word for word interpretation. A concordance will show you every occurrence of a word thus the real meaning. BibleWorks software is good

Comment: @NickRolando also, any academic/scholarly type, jewish or not, can study biblical hebrew in depth, there are academics that study it.. There are many Jews in Israel that may be expert in biblical hebrew but don't have great English, Also, language evolves so it does require expertise to be a biblical hebrew scholar.

Answer (score 2):

An original Tanach in Hebrew is available on [machon-mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm).

A translation is available on [chabad.org](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/732/shmuel-brill).

Comment: there is a translation on machon-mamre as well.

Comment: chabad.org translates [Daniel 9:25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16492) horribly >_<

Comment: @Shredder, If you cannot read Hebrew, how do you know that chabad.org translates the verse terribly?

Comment: @jake I've seen many versions of that verse, Hebrew (translated) and English, and the way that verse is worded in chabad.org doesn't coincide with any of them.

Comment: @Shredder, Then all you can say is that they translate it *differently*, but not necessarily "horribly".

Comment: Actually I have seen chabad.org style translation in most other English translations except Christian ones--who mistranslate it for obvious reasons. If you're looking for a translation that agrees with what you want it to say, then stick with what you already have.

Comment: @Shredder, If you have seen many translations and suspect them to be biased, why would then immediately reject the first translation you saw that differed from them?

Comment: @nickecarlo Actually, I'm looking for one that Jews can agree with that *isn't* biased (for obvious reasons..).

Comment: @SethJ I told Shmuel I took back what I said. Thanks.

Comment: @nickecarlo, "Actually, I'm looking for one that Jews can agree with that isn't biased". Well, _we_ don't think our translation is biased.  :)

Comment: @SethJ I think your comment was meant for Shredder, not me.

Comment: @nickecarlo, You're right. Sorry, I saw your name above his  - my mistake.

Comment: @Shredder As a Christian who talks to Jews on a regular basis, I haven't come across any Jews who don't agree with one Jewish translation of the Tanakh and disagree with another. Of course there are Jewish translations of the Tanakh that are written from different perspectives (literal, meaning-for-meaning, etc) but singling out Jews in that is, quite frankly, silly. Christians have a billion and one translations too, what shall we say about us? As for your Dan 9:25, I am aware of the verse and I'm saying this again, you should be looking at Christian translations to get what you want to see.

Comment: @Shredder I should add to the above that the Jews that I have come across have all said that they prefer the Hebrew Tanakh over any translation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Koren Tanach](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/categories/tanakh) is the best choice.

Comment: Some explanation about why you consider this the best choice would make this answer much more valuable. As it stands, it's just unfounded opinion.

Comment: I agree with Isaac. I'm interested in purchasing, but could explain why this would be the best choice as far as accuracy when compared to the most original scripts?

Comment: http://www.korenpub.com/EN/static/about

Comment: In terms of the textual accuracy, נוסח, the claim is made that Koren is in fact not the 'best.' (See section on 'Criticism'):
http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/תנ%22ך_קורן

R Mordechai Breuer made it his life's work to establish the most 'correct' version which he based on the (remnants of the) Aleppo Codex (the most authoritative text according to Maimonides). The result was printed by Hebrew University as the 'Jerusalem Crown  Bible' --
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Crown
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Breuer